# Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Androidx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: xamarin.android, androidx

I am migrating Xamarin.Android application from Andorid 9 to Android 10. I have updated all the support packages to Andoridx packages.

In .axml files after changing the android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView to androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView , I am getting "Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Androidx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" in the respective .axml.g.cs file.

Attached screenshot of .axml.g.cs file
[image]

I have tried deleting obj, bin folders.
Clean, rebuilt the application. Still not resolved.
Could anyone help me resolving this issue?
Thanks in Advance

activity1.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/Indicator"
            layout="@layout/Indicator" />
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
            />       
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, the namespace is `AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget;` not Androidx.

So you can try to add the following code in the .cs file.

```
using AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget;
or
private AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget.RecyclerView _recycler_view;
```

And then, if it still doesn't work. You can download the nuget package `Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView` from the package manager.

You should create the android layout file such as:

The cause is the nuget package in your project too old. You can try to use a new package to replace it.

Comment: Zhang, Thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention that the screenshot is from .axml.g.cs file which is autogenerated. In the .cs file I have included using AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget;

Comment: When you change the Androidx to the AndroidX, it still doesn't work? @Bhargavi

Comment: Can you show the code in the xaml? @Bhargavi

Comment: The error(Androidx) is in autogenerated file, I suppose that we are not allowed to edit that .g.cs file.

Comment: Is it a xamarin.forms project or a xamarin.android project? @Bhargavi

Comment: Its a Xamarin.Android project. Added the axml code in the Question.

Comment: I had test your code and worked well. In addition, the  .axml.g.cs is the special file in the xamarin.forms. The layout in the android should be the .xml.@Bhargavi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244275/discussion-between-bhargavi-and-liyun-zhang-msft).